# Withdrawing an Etherium Paper wallet

Tags: wallets

Hi i have a few questions about ETH or any other Crypto currency for that matter but maily ETH as im unsure as to the methods available.

### I will address this in the most likley Situation..

I make a Paper wallet myself on lets say EthWallet , online...

I print out my Paper wallet and seal it in a laminator.

Later on in Life ETH Price rockets up and my paper wallet is now worth a Cool 5k

So i decide that i will withdraw my ETH.

I get my Paper wallet and everything is fine. Iv got the Keys.

So i go online to find the EthWallet website.

To my Horror, the website is no longer active...

Now what do i do.

How can i withdraw my ETH now the website where i made the Wallets has gone...

I still have the KEYS though so presumibly i can goto any other ETH withdrawel method ot withdraw it...

(What Are My Options)

I am hoping that as long as i have my Keys (The wallet) i will be able to find any ETH app or platform or wallet and transfare my coin into that wallet from my paper wallet using the private keys.. (am i correct in thinking this) or is there something i am missing...

Thanks for any replys guys...

Comment: As long u have the private key in that paper, you can access the funds. Anyone have access to that private key has also access to the funds

Answer (score 1):

Your funds are stored on the blockchain. As long as you have the private key, you have access to the funds (assuming you're not using a service like Coinbase to store your funds). If a wallet interface goes offline, you can just use another one that has support for private keys and send funds through there.

Make sure to keep multiple backups of the private key (preferably in multiple physical locations). If you lose your private key, there's no way to access your funds anymore. There are some more helpful tips for backing up your private key [here](https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/backup-restore/how-to-save-back-up-your-wallet).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Greatly apreciated the info..